# Could not create Java Virtual Machine javaw.exe. Minecraft

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to make a client using C# that opens `javaw.exe` using some arguments that specifiy launching Minecraft. Yes its pointless but I am doing it for my own research. I can't seem to get it work when using a filepath to the javaw.exe file. Instead it throws up a error stating

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

This error doesn't exactly state what happend. If there is a log, please let me know but as far as me google researching it goes, It can mean 200+ things.

BUT
If I launch it using just the file path `javaw.exe` without defining where it is, it works but I found it doesnt work with others installation of java. Would kinda like to know why this is too but thats a side question.

I have googled everything about this error but there are too many reasons why this is happening so I plan on laying it out in some code to have other help me figure out what exactly is happening.

Java Path Function: (I take no credit for this, aka "stolen code")

```
        private string GetJavaInstallationPath()
        {
            string environmentPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentPath))
            {
                return environmentPath;
            }

            string javaKey = "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\";
            using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(javaKey))
            {
                string currentVersion = rk.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
                using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = rk.OpenSubKey(currentVersion))
                {
                    return key.GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Please note, I removed alot of Libraries from the list below just to make it easier to read the arguments.
Full Code is farther down
Start Minecraft Function:

```
        private void StartMinecraft()
        {
            string installPath = GetJavaInstallationPath();
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(installPath, "bin\\javaw.exe");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                using (Process myProcess = new Process())
                {
                    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)+ "\\AkumaMC\\");

                    string userpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
                    string libpath = userpath + "\\.AkumaMC";
                    string gamepath = libpath;
                    string assetdir = gamepath + "\\assets\\";
                    string accesstoken = accessToken;
                    string argument = "-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -classpath "+ libpath + " -Djava.library.path=" + gamepath + @"\runGame -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.1.5387 -Dminecraft.client.jar=" + libpath + @"\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.jar -cp " + libpath + @"\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.12.2-14.23.5.2838\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2838.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\launchwrapper-1.12.jar;" + libpath + @"\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.jar -Xmx"+(SettingsUC.ramInt / 1024).ToString()+@"G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dlog4j.configurationFile=" + libpath + @"\assets\log_configs\client-1.12.xml net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch --username " + uname + @" --version 1.12.2-forge --gameDir " + libpath + " --assetsDir " + libpath + @"\assets --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid " + uuidPlayer + @" --accessToken " + accesstoken + @" --userType mojang --tweakClass net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker --versionType Forge";

                    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
                    Console.WriteLine(filePath + argument);
                    Console.WriteLine((SettingsUC.ramInt / 1024).ToString() + " Is the GB #");
                    myProcess.Start();
                    if (!SettingsUC.KeepLauncherOpen == true)
                    {
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }

                //Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find Java installation. Please reinstall the latest version of Java and try again.", "AkumaMC Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }
```

Full Start Minecraft Function:

```
        private void StartMinecraft()
        {
            string installPath = GetJavaInstallationPath();
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(installPath, "bin\\javaw.exe");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                using (Process myProcess = new Process())
                {
                    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)+ "\\AkumaMC\\");

                    string userpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
                    string libpath = userpath + "\\.AkumaMC";
                    string gamepath = libpath;
                    string assetdir = gamepath + "\\assets\\";
                    string accesstoken = accessToken;
                    string argument = "-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -classpath "+ libpath + " -Djava.library.path=" + gamepath + @"\runGame -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.1.5387 -Dminecraft.client.jar=" + libpath + @"\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.jar -cp " + libpath + @"\libraries\net\minecraftforge\forge\1.12.2-14.23.5.2838\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2838.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\launchwrapper-1.12.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\5.2\asm-all-5.2.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\jline\jline\3.5.1\jline-3.5.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\typesafe\akka\akka-actor_2.11\2.3.3\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\typesafe\config\1.2.1\config-1.2.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-actors-migration_2.11\1.1.0\scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.11.1\scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-library_2.11\1.0.2\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\1.0.2\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.11.1\scala-library-2.11.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.11.1\scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-swing_2.11\1.0.1\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\scala-lang\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.2\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\lzma\lzma\0.0.1\lzma-0.0.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.5.2\vecmath-1.5.2.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\apache\maven\maven-artifact\3.5.3\maven-artifact-3.5.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\mojang\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.10.22\realms-1.10.22.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\fastutil-7.1.0.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;" + libpath + @"\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;" + libpath + @"\versions\1.12.2\1.12.2.jar -Xmx"+(SettingsUC.ramInt / 1024).ToString()+@"G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dlog4j.configurationFile=" + libpath + @"\assets\log_configs\client-1.12.xml net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch --username " + uname + @" --version 1.12.2-forge --gameDir " + libpath + " --assetsDir " + libpath + @"\assets --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid " + uuidPlayer + @" --accessToken " + accesstoken + @" --userType mojang --tweakClass net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker --versionType Forge";

                    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
                    Console.WriteLine(filePath + argument);
                    Console.WriteLine((SettingsUC.ramInt / 1024).ToString() + " Is the GB #");
                    myProcess.Start();
                    if (!SettingsUC.KeepLauncherOpen == true)
                    {
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }

                //Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find Java installation. Please reinstall the latest version of Java and try again.", "AkumaMC Fatal Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        }
```

I expected it to launch minecraft, instead it just throws a error. Although if I change

```
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
TO
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "javaw.exe";
```

It works, but only for my java installation (so I think)

Thanks for all the help given!

UPDATE: After feedback, i think its due the fact thats its in a folder with spaces. So, is there a way to pulle a regkey value fully. Upon searching, i found that key.GetValue().ToString() only returns a string of the first word, not the "sentence" or "full path".

Comment: Just a wild guess: does any of your paths contain whitespaces? If so you need to put them inside of the quotation marks

Comment: You could be on to something, I just tried to paste in my dir to my specific java and it worked... maybe something wrong with the Find Java Path Function. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your side-question on why it works if you ommit the full path and just call javaw.exe directly: most likely this works because the java installation was written into your PATH environment variable (which also makes it callable from commandline) navigate to: WIN+Break >> Advanced SystemSettings(?) >> Environment variables. Check if the path to your java-installation is registered in the PATH-variable. If it is not there, calling javaw.exe without the full path will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like with the comments on the post, I was able to narrow it down and fix the issue. It was looking for a 32bit version of the registry for the java location. Most people have 64bit at this point so I just added a check for the operating system, then checked the registry for that operating system.

If you are interested in doing this yourself, I recommend using the updated code below that better tracks the correct java folder.

```
        private string GetJavaInstallationPath()
        {
            string environmentPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentPath))
            {
                return environmentPath;
            }
            string javaKey = "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\";
            if (!Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(javaKey))
                {
                    string currentVersion = rk.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
                    using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = rk.OpenSubKey(currentVersion))
                    {
                        return key.GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();//Not Pullying full string
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var view64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                                            RegistryView.Registry64))
                {
                    using (var clsid64 = view64.OpenSubKey(javaKey))
                    {
                        string currentVersion = clsid64.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
                        using (RegistryKey key = clsid64.OpenSubKey(currentVersion))
                        {
                            return key.GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();//Not Pullying full string
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```